# How to produce a graph of connected data in Python?

Tags: python, graph

Let's say I have a table of words, and each word has a "related words" column. In practice, this would probably be two tables with a one-to-many relationship, as each word can have more than one "related words" columns, but for simplicity, say it looks like this:

```
Word      | Related words
------------------------------------------------------
integer   | fraction, entire, integral ...
entire    | entirely, integer ...
fraction  | fractious, fractional, integer ...
fractious | fraction, -ous ...
-ous      | ambidextrous, advantageous, atrocious ...
```

And so on. I want to create a graph which shows how all of the words interlink, based on the relationships I've described in this table.

I've found [an online tool](https://csacademy.com/app/graph_editor/) which does exactly what I want, and used it to produce an example:

[image]

Is there a Python module which can be used to produce this sort of graph? I'm not too sure what this kind of graph is called, so I'm not sure how to research this question. I'd appreciate any pointers, or advice on how I can clarify and improve this question if needed.

Comment: how about https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/ ? (not making this an answer, as recommending libraries is off-topic anyway)

Comment: Thanks, Graphviz looks like exactly what I'm looking for! Where would library recommendations be on topic on SE out of interest? I feel like Python has so many libraries that I often need to get some pointers about which one actually solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) is a Python package for the creation, manipulation of complex graph networks. It also supports interfacing with Matplotlib package for [drawing the graphs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#drawing-graphs).

Comment: Both NetworkX and GraphViz look really helpful, thanks for the answer!