# How can I create dynamic sub-graphs within an extremely large graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198335/how-to-produce-a-graph-of-connected-data-in-python), I have a table of words, and for each word there is a column with a list of "related words". Here is example data:

```
Word      | Related words
------------------------------------------------------
integer   | fraction, entire, integral ...
entire    | entirely, integer ...
fraction  | fractious, fractional, integer ...
fractious | fraction, -ous ...
-ous      | ambidextrous, advantageous, atrocious ...
```

I can use NetworkX in Python to load this data into an undirected graph, as below:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()

words = {'integer': ['entire', 'fraction', 'integral'],
'entire': ['entirely'],
'fraction': ['fractious', 'fractional'],
'fractious': ['-ous'],
'-ous': ['ambidextrous', 'advantageous', 'atrocious']}
for key, value in words.items():
    for word in value:
        G.add_edge(key, word)

plt.show()
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True,font_weight='bold')
```

And that generates an output just fine, as in the image below:

[image]

The problem is, this doesn't scale well at all. I have nearly 50,000 words, and I'd estimate around 300,000 "related words" - that's a lot of nodes and edges.

What I would love is a way to be able to see a certain portion of the chart at the time, and dynamically move the selection. For example, if I wanted to see all nodes connected to the word "integer", then in the example below I would click on "integer", and all nodes at least 2 edges away are revealed - essentially creating a new graph with "integer" at the centre - with irrelevant nodes hidden from view. I would also want to be able to search for a word and produce a sub-graph of just that word, and change the "size" of the graph - i.e. the number of edges away from the central node to display.

Is this kind of function possible with networkx? I'm sure I can create a sub-graph for any given word just fine, but I don't know how to implement a behaviour where I can use the graph itself as an interactive tool, or whether this is even possible using matplotlib and networkx. If not, is there a better means to create such an interactive graph in Python?

Comment: There are many implementations of `visual dictionaries` online. These tend to be interactive and clickable, exactly as you describe. Take a look at https://visuwords.com/ for one example. Click on words to see the behavior. Now, Networkx+Matplotlib is fine for static images, but you might need a javascript based backend. There are Python frameworks that do this, but you would have to combine the animations with the nextworkx properties you desire. Take a quick look at pyCairo. Ask around and those who work with JS can give you more suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for giving me an idea of where to start! Looks like the scope of the project might be beyond my current knowledge, but I may start with working out how to get a slice of the big graph.

Comment: As @RamNarasimhan stated, networkx/matplotlib is best for static images, plotly builds interactive graphs where you can select/zoom in on certain portions and display information on hover and it has network functionality. See https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/